# How to store global variable in one ajax file and get from another ajax file?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Suppose i have 2 ajax file.. first.js and second.js .

if i write a global variable in second.js like this-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var globalData = null;
$.ajax(){
     url: //statement,
     type: //statement,
     data: //statement,
    success:  {
                  
        success: function(response){

           // Show response
          
           if(condition) // this condition is not a variable  but a 'if condition'
           {
              globalData=1;
              
           }else{
              globalData=0;
           }
               }
}
```

Now how can i get the **globalData** variable in first.js ?

Comment: Can you tell us what your need is? And not how to implement a solution? Why do you need to share those variables? Maybe we can find a better solution.

Comment: `globalData` is not as global as you think it is.

Comment: @HassenCh. in my second.js i use to verify if a username if available or not  and then in first.js where the submit form is available, i want to use that global variable to check if the username is available , if not then disable the form submit button. else let user submit. That's the logic

Comment: @Andy can u show me how to fix that?

Comment: @jerry you're using the wrong approach. You should pass the parameter of "username" to a function that will check if it's available of not. And then you use that output to know if you should let the user submit the form or not. Using "global" variables is completely wrong.

Comment: Without understanding how that data is being used in `first.js` not really. Perhaps you could describe in (edit) your question what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the variable to be global remove the `var` keyword. Note that it only works in [sloppy mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Sloppy_mode), and it is a bad practice in general. Prefer chaining asynchronous operations instead of sharing variables between them.

Indeed, you never know if the variable is set or not, by writing this kind of code.

[Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) are very helpful with this, and there is an alternative to [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) that returns [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise): [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Here is a simple example of what you're trying to do with a global [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to ensure that the data is there when you need it:

```
// first.js 
const first = fetch(firstUrl, { method: ..., body: ... }).then(x => {
  // Some logic
  return globalData;
});

// second.js
const second = first.then(globalData => fetch(secondUrl, { method: ..., body: ... }));
```

In this example I kept the `globalData` name to show how it is equivalent to your code, but it's not accurate anymore and should be changed for better clarity.

Comment: can you show a small code sample about how to get the global variable ?

Comment: My advice is precisely not to use global variables, but if you want to do so just remove `var`

Comment: The old-school method is to use object namespacing.